# Using preg_replace to transform URLs in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to take a string of HTML and, for all URLs in the string that end in "_page.php" & transform them so that they consist of ONLY the basename and "_page" so for example with this string:

```
<br/>http://www.website.com/folder/A_page.php TEXT
<br/>http://www.website.com/folder/B_page.php TEXT
<br/>http://www.website.com/folder/C_page.php TEXT
<br/>http://www.website.com/folder/D_dont.php TEXT
```

I want it to look like:

```
<br/>A_page TEXT
<br/>B_page TEXT
<br/>C_page TEXT
<br/>http://www.website.com/folder/D_dont.php TEXT
```

I wrote this:

```
$str = preg_replace('!(http)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?&_/]+_page.php!', '$0',$str);
```

which gets the right amount of matches, but it is replacing them with $0 which is the entire matched URL so it doesn't change the URLs at all. Doing this:

```
$str = preg_replace('!(http)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?&_/]+_page.php!', '$1',$str);
```

Gets me:

```
http TEXT 
http TEXT 
http TEXT 
http://www.website.com/folder/D_dont.php TEXT
```

So I figured if I switched the $1 to $2 it would return the body of the URL which I could parse and return like this:

```
$str = preg_replace('!(http)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?&_/]+_page.php!', basename('$2','.php'),$str);
```

$2 turns up empty though. How can I capture the body of the link in preg_replace?

Comment: `$2` is either `s` or empty as it is what `(s)?` captures.Use `!https?://[a-zA-Z0-9.?&_/]*/([^/]*_page)\.php!` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: To use `basename('$2','.php')` or any function as the replacement you need `preg_replace_callback()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all those parentheses.  For this pattern just use them to capture `(/.*_page.php)` and that is `$1`:

```
$str = preg_replace('!https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?&_/]+(/.*_page.php)!', '$1', $str);
```

To use functions in the replace use a callback.  Match the entire URL and then get the basename from that which in this case is `$0` or `$m[0]`:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('!https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?&_/]+_page.php!',
                             function($m) { return basename($m[0]); },
                             $str);
```

Comment: Thank you! you explained it well.